# socket.io RAM usage goes up over time

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What can I do to keep ram at a reasonable level?
Before i start the server I have about 140mb ram free.
After 16 hours i have about 4mb free ram left.
I'm running this on a rackspace cloud with 256mb ram.

```
var maxMsgs = 50;
var express = require('express'), sio = require('socket.io'), redis = require('redis'), RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis');
var app = express.createServer(), pub = redis.createClient(), sub = redis.createClient(), client = redis.createClient();
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(8002, function () {
  var addr = app.address();
  console.log('app listening on http://' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});

var io = sio.listen(app, {log: false}), nicknames = {}, history = [], user_count = 0, topic = {topic: '', setBy: 'Server'}, ytvid = {vid: '', setBy: 'Server'};
io.enable('browser client minification');
io.enable('browser client etag');
io.enable('browser client gzip');
io.set('store', new RedisStore({redisPub : pub, redisSub : sub, redisClient : client}));
//io.set('resource', 'socket');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('join', function(cu) {
    if(cu.username && cu.username != 'Guest') {
      socket.nickname = cu.username;
      socket.emit('connected', nicknames, history, topic, ytvid);
      nicknames[cu.username] = cu;
      socket.broadcast.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
      user_count++;
      //socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', {msg: socket.nickname + ' connected'});
    }
  });
  socket.on('message', function(msg, cb) {
    if(msg.msg && msg.msg != '') {
      msg.time = Date.now() / 1000;
      history.push(msg);
      while(history.length > maxMsgs) history.shift();
      cb(true, msg.time);
      socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    }
  });
  socket.on('stopic', function(t) {
    if(t.topic && t.setBy && t.topic != '') {
      topic = t;
      io.sockets.emit('topic', t);
    } else {
      topic = {topic: 'No topic set', setBy: 'Admin'};
      io.sockets.emit('topic', topic);
    }
  });
  socket.on('sytvid', function(v) {
    if(v.vid && v.setBy && v.vid != '') {
      ytvid = v;
      io.sockets.emit('ytvid', v);
    } else {
      ytvid = {vid: false, setBy: 'Admin'};
      io.sockets.emit('ytvid', ytvid);
    }
  });
  socket.on('get debug', function() {
    socket.emit('debug', {users: nicknames, history: history, user_count: user_count, topic: topic});
  });
  socket.on('send command', function(c) {
    if(c.type == 'empty') history = [];
    io.sockets.emit('command', c);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    if(!socket.nickname) return;
    if(!nicknames[socket.nickname]) return;
    //nicknames[socket.nickname].status = 'offline';
    delete nicknames[socket.nickname];
    //socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', {msg: socket.nickname + ' disconnected'});
    socket.broadcast.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
    user_count--;
  });
});

function inArray(needle,haystack){for(var key in haystack){if(needle===haystack[key]){return true;}}return false;}
function zeroPad(digits,n){n=n.toString();while(n.length<digits){n='0'+n;}return n;}
function time(time){if(time==null)time=new Date();else if((time instanceof Date)===false)time=new Date(time);return time;}
```

Comment: Like this for instance teamspeak3 has been running for 106 hours and node for 46 hours yet teamspeak3 uses 0.8% ram while node is using 46.5% of the ram surely i made a mistake somewhere i just cant see it :( [Console image of ram usage](http://thecoderguy.org/ss/20120617-8d6-23kb.jpg).

Comment: I am wondering if my answer helped you enough to close this topic? Else what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem in socket.on('join') point.

I recommend you to start using

```
var profiler = require('v8-profiler');
setInterval(function() {
    profiler.takeSnapshot('snappy');
},1000);
```

like described here http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler

So you will now where is your leak starts.

Also carefully check allocation and deallocation of each variable, object and scope.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: i will certainly do this thanks i wasnt aware there was a profiler but then ive never look lol. Thanks Dave

Comment: I have one question where is the log stored i looked in standard places and cant see it i know i know dumb question but is 1am and have school run in 7 hours lol :)

Answer (score 0):

[Some people think that socket.io leaks memory when using websockets transport](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/880). Try to disable it. Something along the lines of:

```
io.configure('production', function(){
  io.enable('browser client etag');
  io.set('log level', 1);

  io.set('transports', [
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
});
```

[Also heroku has to say the following](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)

Comment: I don't really want to use polling, i looked though those links and it seems to me the only error is someone failing to destroy the socket on disconnect not sure if that's in socket.io or node itself but if polling works i will use that for now until my prob is resolved :)

Comment: Im still going to try the answer below just to make sure ive not made fails also :D

Comment: Cant believe i actually got help on this, everyone i meet knows nothing of programming there only a handful of members that can code on our site the other 100000+ cant do anything and just suck up our bandwidth :D, Thanks so much